# Should doxxing be allowed here?

Tags: discussion

In the comments of [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/37185/how-reliable-is-the-research-behind-the-flu-vaccine-reducing-hospital-acquired-f), the poster gave what he seems to think is the real name of one of our moderators.   Personally, I'm not terribly well hidden here, but pseudonyms are allowable, and doxxing feels like something chilling to the free exchange of ideas, and in the context of the discussion, feels like it was intended to be something of a threat.

Should there be a policy on behavior like that?

UPDATE: the question has been removed.

Comment: It's an occupational hazard of being a moderator - if your real name is on the internet, anywhere, you can assume that at some point, a disgruntled user *will* find it and post it.

Comment: Right, but does that make it tolerable behavior?

Comment: Not at all - just an observation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The following section in the [terms of service](http://stackexchange.com/legal) would apply here:

> Under no circumstances will Subscriber use the Network or the Service
>   to (a) [...] (b) harass, threaten, stalk or abuse any person or party,
>   including other users of the Network,

Also the ["be nice" section](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) of the help center outlining the code of conduct on SE has a relevant section:

> Harassment and bullying. If you see a hostile interaction, flag it. If
>   it keeps up, disengage — we'll handle it. If something needs staff
>   attention, you can use the contact us link at the bottom of every page

In short, doxxing is against the rules and if you see an instance, flag for moderator attention and we'll deal with it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure a moderator saw it, since it was a moderator that the user doxxed. ;]  But in the future, that's what I'll do.